# How does LaTex set the English numbered prefix for the bilingual header picture list?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, lists, bicaption

When using bicaption package to generate the bilingual title of the graph, I output Lists of tables and figures separately, but the number prefix of English Lists of tables and figures is still Chinese. How to change 图 1.1 of LOF and LOT to Figure 1.1 and Table 1.1.

```
\usepackage{bicaption}  
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}  
\captionsetup[figure][bi-second]{name=Figure}   
\captionsetup[table][bi-second]{name=Table}   
\captionsetup[figure][bi-second]{listtype+=Eng}  
\captionsetup[table][bi-second]{listtype+=Eng}  
 \usepackage{newfloat}  
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lof2]{figureEng}[Figure][List of Figures]  
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lot2]{tableEng}[Table][List of Tables]


\begin{document}  
\listoffigures  
\listoffigureEng  

\listoftables  
\listoftableEng
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The code in your question is not really complete, it does not contain any figures or tables. Because you use dual captions (which is not very common) it is important that you add the missing code yourself to make it clear how exactly the figures and captions are being used. Therefore please post a complete document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that can be compiled without errors and shows the relevant output. It doesn't need to be 20 pages, just one figure, one table, the LOFs and LOFs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the `\PrepareListOf` command to deal with this issue. This solution come from the `newfloat` package. Just type the following codes after declares:

```
\PrepareListOf{figureEng}{\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Fig.~}}
\PrepareListOf{tableEng}{
    \renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Table~}
    \cftsetindents{fig}{0em}{4.5em}
}
```

Note that the commands in `\PrepareListOf` changed the commands setting in `listoffigures`.